# Finding Laurent Series of for the annulus $1<|z|<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have the following function and I want to find the Laurent Series. We already have the answer but I don't know/understand how I can get there :

Let

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^2}+\frac{1}{3-z}$$

For the annulus : $1<|z|<3$

Any help would be a lot appreciated.

Comment: Arround which point ? btw your function is holomorphic on $1<|z|<3$, so laurent and taylor series coincides.

Comment: centred in zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull out $-1/{z^{2}}$ from the first term and $\frac  1 3$ from the second.

$f(z)=-\frac   1{z^{2}}  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac  1 {z^{2}})^{k}+\frac  1 3 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac  z 3)^{k} $.

Comment: There is no $n$ to truncate to a given order provided.

Comment: @AHusain That was a typo. Thanks for pointing out.